How to use Power Automate to create child tasks when new work item is created in Azure DevOps
I want to create a flow in power automate that will automatically create child tasks every time a parent work item is created in Azure DevOps. Those new child tasks should be linked in the parent work item under Related Work.

I found some instructions here: https://manueltgomes.com/azure/devops/create-tasks-automatically/ and it worked!

Glad to know that you have found some instruction about the issue. You can post your solution in answer, and this may benefit others who have the same question.

Are you still looking for a solution to be posted @BabyBear ?
